# Is there a view where I can print each individual response separately?

Tags: cognito-forms

I have posted a survey and I can see all the responses on one spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

To print an individual form entry:

1. Go to your form's Entries page.
2. Select an individual entry to expand
   the entry details.
3. Click the Print button at the top of the page to
   open your browser’s print dialog.
4. Specify your printer settings and
   print out the entry.